# How does one create a EOS paper wallet?

Tags: wallet

Is there a way to create paper wallet for EOS cold storage? And can these addresses also receive tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've integrated EOS key generation into my memory paper wallet generator project as seen below:

Live Demo: https://xcubicle.github.io/memorypaperwallet

Details: https://www.xcubicle.com/memory-paper-wallet-bitcoin-ethereum-monero-ardor-litecoin

Features:

- Key generation is time and memory intensive to prevent brute force guessing
- Printer friendly design
- Fold to conceal the private keys when giving as a gift.
- Background is user changeable for different occasions
- Ability to generate multi-party keys using Shamir Secret Sharing Scheme.
- Remember a user/pass combination to generate the same keys in case of loss when giving away as gifts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate a keypair using [`eosjs-ecc`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc), create an account that uses that keypair for owner key, and keep your private key safe.

Example process:

1. Install the library

   ```
   $ npm install eosjs-ecc
   ```
2. Create a keypair

   ```
   $ node
   > const ecc = require('eosjs-ecc')
   > ecc.randomKey().then(privateKey => {
      console.log('Private Key:\t', privateKey) // wif
      console.log('Public Key:\t',  ecc.privateToPublic(privateKey)) // EOSkey...
     })
   > Private Key: 5KCyCHxCRwV7EH5VWUt2AFeVo2vRu2HgBGFsAwoF5CokwTa4mEa
   Public Key: EOS8E8FjakRz1a5Tw4YJQb6QMFC6ah1SWf3LEBpHCffH48G7mYWMj
   ```
3. Import the private key in your wallet

   ```
   $ cleos wallet import 5KCyCHxCRwV7EH5VWUt2AFeVo2vRu2HgBGFsAwoF5CokwTa4mEa
   ```
4. Create an account with that key

   ```
   $ cleos system newaccount <parent-account> <new-account> <public-key> --stake-net 10.0000 EOS --stake-cpu 10.0000 EOS --buy-ram-kbytes 20
   ```
5. Write your private key somewhere safe offline

Note that this process can be made more secure using typical paper wallet practices such as using a newly installed operating system on an air-gapped machine, using multisig, creating a hierarchy of permissions, etc.